# Well, i have been trying to make a die roller where the user selects a 4 sided d

Tags: javascript, html, variables

So, I have been trying to make a dice roller. So the user selects how many sides it has, and then how many of those dice to roll, for example two 10 sided dice. Then the system makes a random number in between one and the amount of sides the selected die has.

So here is what I did:

```
<input type="numbers" name="dieAmount" value="Type Die Amount Here">
<select id="dieType">
<option value="0"> Select Die Type</option>  
<option value="20"> d20 </option>
<option value="12"> d12 </option>
<option value="10"> d10 </option>
<option value="8"> d8 </option>
<option value="6"> d6 </option>
<option value="4"> d4 </option>
<option value="2"> d2 </option>
</select> 
<p>

<input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="roll(dieType)" />
</form>


<script>
function roll(){
var min= 1; 
var max = document.getElementById("dieType").value;  
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + min
var factor = document.getElementById("dieAmount").value;
 var outcome = random * factor - 1
document.write("Number Rolled: " + outcome);  
 }
</script>
```

I just can't figure out how to make the select and input blocks to become a variable.

Comment: "I just can't figure out how to make the select and sum=bmit blocks become a variable." No clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only missed to define an `id` attribute for dieAmount (and you don't need a `name` attribute there)... And, you can't access the select current value simply by value, but you should use the element's option selectedIndex...
See my code:

```
<input type="numbers" id="dieAmount" value="Type Die Amount Here">
<select id="dieType">
  <option value="0"> Select Die Type</option>  
  <option value="20"> d20 </option>
  <option value="12"> d12 </option>
  <option value="10"> d10 </option>
  <option value="8"> d8 </option>
  <option value="6"> d6 </option>
  <option value="4"> d4 </option>
  <option value="2"> d2 </option>
</select> 
<p>
<input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="roll(dieType)" />

<script>
function roll() {
  var factor = document.getElementById("dieAmount").value;
  var dieTypeElement = document.getElementById("dieType");
  var max = dieTypeElement.options[dieTypeElement.selectedIndex].value;
  var min = 1; 
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  var outcome = random * factor - 1;
  document.write("Number Rolled: " + outcome);  
}
</script>
```